# How to add child elements using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this below input request. we will be getting nearly 10 tags containing Book and Date info..I want that each info to be in between the tag `<shop>`. How should I write this in xslt ?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:p="http://www.blah.com">
     <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <p:order>
    <p:shop>
    <p:Book>Guru</p:Book>
    <p:date>12-2-2020</p:date>
    <p:Book>jungle</p:Book>
    <p:date>13-1-2023</p:date>
    <p:Book>Sports</p:Book>
    <p:date>13-1-2023</p:date>
    </p:shop>
    </p:order>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Expected Output:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:p="http://www.blah.com">
         <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
        <p:order>
        <p:shop>
        <p:Author>Guru</p:Author>
        <p:startdate>12-2-2020</p:startdate>
        <p:shop>
        <p:Author>jungle</p:Author>
        <p:startdate>13-1-2023<p:/startdate>
        <p:shop>
        <p:Author>Sports</p:Author>
        <p:startdate>13-1-2023</p:startdate>
        </p:shop>
        </p:order>
    <e:shop>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

My xslt:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//Order">
                           <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::date[1]"/>
                         <p:Author>
                             <xsl:value-of select="$Book"/>
                          </p:Author>
                           <p:StartDate>
                             <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
                          </p:StartDate>
                     </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you show is not well-formed XML. Assuming you want to get an output of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:p="http://www.blah.com">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <p:order>
      <p:shop>
        <p:Book>Guru</p:Book>
        <p:date>12-2-2020</p:date>
      </p:shop>
      <p:shop>
        <p:Book>jungle</p:Book>
        <p:date>13-1-2023</p:date>
      </p:shop>
      <p:shop>
        <p:Book>Sports</p:Book>
        <p:date>13-1-2023</p:date>
      </p:shop>
    </p:order>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:p="http://www.blah.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p:shop">
    <xsl:for-each select="p:Book">
        <p:shop>
            <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::p:date[1]"/>
        </p:shop>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But Michael,can we write without using template ? My xslt is so lengthy, I pasted only a bit in this question. I'm getting error that template cannot be used as a child element..Is their any other way please ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the problem. Perhaps you need to post another question.

Comment: I think I should post another qquestion. But I'm afraid it may be tagged as similar question and get flagged. Will post another question.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't something like this suffice?

```
 <p:order>
     <xsl:for-each select="//p:order/p:shop/p:Book">
         <p:shop>
         <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::p:date[1]"/>
         
         <p:Author>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
          </p:Author>
           <p:StartDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::p:date[1]"/>
          </p:StartDate>
          </p:shop>
     </xsl:for-each>
     </p:order>
```

produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:order xmlns:p="http://www.blah.com">
   <p:shop>12-2-2020
<p:Author>Guru</p:Author>
      <p:StartDate>12-2-2020</p:StartDate>
   </p:shop>
   <p:shop>13-1-2023
<p:Author>jungle</p:Author>
      <p:StartDate>13-1-2023</p:StartDate>
   </p:shop>
   <p:shop>13-1-2023
<p:Author>Sports</p:Author>
      <p:StartDate>13-1-2023</p:StartDate>
   </p:shop>
</p:order>
```

i removed the variables since i have no clue on how they are declared in your stylesheet.